# JQuery Form Cache File

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently developing a mobile app that calculates the users GPA. One feature I want to add is the ability for the inputted data to be saved through cache data or another method similar. Is it possible to save all of the inputs including the drop down responses through a save button which stores the data? Or something similar?

```js
var $oBox = $('.outer-box');
var $gpa = $('#gpa');
var $result = $('.result').hide();

 $('#btnAddClass').click(function() {
      $('.block').last().clone().children().val("").parent().appendTo($('.inner-box'));
     $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
  }, 'slow');
  return false;
    });

$oBox.on('keyup', '.credits', function() {
  $gpa.text(getTotal());
});

$oBox.on("change", ".grade-select", function() {
 
});

function getTotal() {
  var gradeTotal = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  $(".credits").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!isNaN($this.val()) && !isNaN($this.parent().find('.grade-select').val())) {
      sum += parseFloat($this.val() || 0) * parseFloat($this.parent().find('.grade-select').val() || 0);
      gradeTotal += parseFloat($this.val() || 0)
    }
  });
  return (sum / gradeTotal).toFixed(2);
}

$("#Calculate").on("click", function() {
 $gpa.text(getTotal());
  $result.is(":hidden") && $result.show();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
  }, 'slow');
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
          <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href="http://maltertech.com/bootstrap.min.css">

    <head>
        <style>
          body {
    background-color: #A00000;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.outer-box {
    height: true;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}
.block {
    margin: 5px;
}
.class {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.credits {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 95px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.grade-select {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 95px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.btn {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
#Calculate {
    width: 200px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
.result {
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
#gpa {
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
          </style>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>GPA Calculator</title>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <div class='outer-box'>
                <div class='inner-box'>
                    <form class='block'>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <input type="text" class='class' placeholder="Class">
                            </tr>
                            <br>
                            <tr>
                                <select class='credits'>
                                    <option value="">Credits</option>
                                    <option value="0.5">Half Year</option>
                                    <option value="1">Full Year</option>
                                </select>
                                <select class='grade-select'>
                                    <option value="">Grade</option>
                                    <option value="4.6">A+</option>
                                    <option value="4.0">A</option>
                                    <option value="3.6">B+</option>
                                    <option value="3.0">B</option>
                                    <option value="2.6">C+</option>
                                    <option value="2.0">C</option>
                                    <option value="1.0">D</option>
                                    <option value="0.0">F</option>
                                </select>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id='btnAddClass' class='btn btn-default'>Add Class</div>
                <br>
                <button id="Calculate" class='btn btn-default' >Calculate</button>
                <div class='result'>
                    <h3 id="gpa">GPA</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </center>
    <script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How long do you want to save the data for (indefinitely, until the user closes the app, etc.)? Is this a mobile application running in a browser or in a hybrid app framework as a native app?

Comment: Indefinitely until a reset cache button is clicked. Running in a hybrid app framework as a native app @J.Titus

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serialize()` to get all the values from the form(you also have to give your inputs and select names for serialize to work) and you can use `localStorage()` to save the data like:

```
var form_data = $(".block").serialize();
localStorage.setItem('data', form_data);
```

Then, if you want, you can delete the data saved in local storage like this:

```
localStorage.removeItem('data');
```

Example **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kjh6g7k1/)**.

Check the console to see the stored data in local storage.

You can read more about `localStorage()` **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**.

Comment: So how do I have it pull the stored data when it is opened?

Comment: @Zachmalter, what do you mean? What is when opened?

Comment: Yea. is that localStorage.setItem('data', form_data);

Comment: @Zachmalter, you're a bit unclear. Can you please explain? Is there a problem?

Comment: Could you please demonstrate it in a snippet? @ionut

Comment: There are literally hundreds of tutorials out there that deal with reading from and writing to localStorage. Google and StackOverflow are your best friends.

Comment: @Zachmalter, I've added an minimal working example fiddle to my updated answer. See that I've explained that you also have to add names to your inputs and selects.